# permission errors in making multiple sub directories php

Tags: php

Hi im building a website that requires the dynamic build of a filestructer based on user regestration details, this would be in the creation of a usr directory, the subdirectory level would be the id of the directory based on a php script, this so far i can create no issues with chmod 777. however when i try and create subdirectories in the id directory such as an images folder then a html folder and a css folder i keep getting permission errors. the server is a linux server on my resellers hosting account

following is the php code

```
$dirPath = "../userDirectory/$diectoryid/";
```

echo $dirPath;

```
mkdir ('$dirPath/image/',0777,true);
```

Comment: So what permissions are created on those created folders? We cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: userDirectory and $directoryid are both chmod 777

Comment: No, I did not ask for the command you try to execute, but for the actual permissions the folders do get. Just take a look be it inside the file system or via php. Without look at it you are flying in the dark and trying to guess what might work. That does not make sense.

Comment: that is the permissions set on the folders userDirectory and the dynamically created folder on the server created by the script

Comment: I have the impression you confuse the command `chmod` with the actual permissions. The command _tries_ to set permissions. But that does _not_ mean these permissions are set. Various aspects may come in between. That is why it makes sense to take a look at the actual permissions. Why don't you simply do it? Look at the folders. Why user and group do they belong to? What permissions do they have?

Comment: Oh, and by the way: this line does not make sense: `mkdir ('$dirPath/image/',0777,true);`. `$dirPath` will _not_ get expanded but be taken literal here, due to the single quotes. So you create a folder called `$dirPath`... Either use double quotes or a concatenation.

Comment: no im not confusing the chmod command with the permissions of the actual folders, i checked the permissions as you requested on the server and as i said they have been set as 777. And thankyou, pointing out the error in my quotes fixed my issue

Comment: OK, that is a reply. Though: you did _not_ say so before. You wrote: "userDirectory and $directoryid are both chmod 777" which does not make any sense (not trying to be picky here. But precision makes sense in technical details...). Now next: what user and group account? Without that the numerical permissions are useless... Can the http server process write or not?

Comment: as you didnt put the comments as an answer i cant give you the credit you deserve for a correct answer

Comment: Ah, so you mean your issue actually was the quoting? Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

When you use single quotes, PHP will interpret that literally. So in your case it will try to create: $dirPath/image/ (not the VALUE of $dirPath, but $dirPath as the name)

Replace your second line of code with:

```
mkdir($dirPath . 'image/', 0777, true);
```

Provided the rest of your code is fine, it should create the folder without errors.

Comment: Yes, that has been mentioned in the comments 10 minutes before you posted your answer.

Comment: That must have been under 'show 5 more comments then' - didn't notice it :-)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments before this detail actually was causing the problem here, not the actual file permissions:

This line does not make sense: `mkdir ('$dirPath/image/',0777,true);`. `$dirPath` will not get expanded but be taken literal here, due to the single quotes. So you create a folder called `$dirPath`... Either use double quotes or a concatenation:

Either:

```
mkdir ("$dirPath/image/",0777,true);
```

Or:

```
mkdir ($dirPath . '/image/',0777,true);
```

Comment: @JeroenFlamman First that depends on the content of `$dirpath` obviously and second that would not make a difference in the action, so actually make things more robust because in case `$dirPath` does _not_ contain a trailing slash things would break again otherwise. So I would prefer it this way :-)